# Controller config window doesn't work in pcsxr(PCSX-RELOADED)

Tags: 18.04, plugins, emulation

I installed pscxr(playstation emulator) from ubuntu software and everything seems to work fine except for the controller config window, when i click on the controller settings nothing happens. I'm on ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Do you mean pcsxr as in "PCSX-Reloaded"?  If so, you should edit your post to clarify this item.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1173751/how-can-make-the-controler-configuration-window-show-in-pcsxr