# How can make the controler configuration window show in pcsxr?

Tags: 18.04, gamepad, emulation, pcsx

I'm running ubuntu 18.04 and have installed pcsxr via `apt`. Everything seems to work as expected except for controllers. When I try to click on the controller icon or select "controllers..." from the configuration menu, nothing works at all. Nothing is printed to stderr either.

My controller is being detected properly by the system (lsusb) and works with other games and emulators without issue.

It seems that at least one other person [attempted to ask the same question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080411/controller-config-window-doesnt-work-in-pcsxrpcsx-reloaded?rq=1) before, but unfortunately, their question was locked without any answers. That is why I'm posting a new question.

How can I get pcsxr to detect my control and show the configuration window?

Comment: @Jos I actually have the solution. I posted this question again so that I can answer it myself since the solution is berried deep within an obscure German site.  I would answer the original question but it is locked.

Comment: Ok, I removed my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 shipped with many broken packages, and pcsxr is one of them. Fortunately, pcsxr is among the few packages that can be easily fixed. The solution is to install the functioning input plugin from the 16.04 version of pcsxr. (All credit goes to [josefien](https://gathering.tweakers.net/forum/list_messages/1944442) for figuring this out)

1. Install pcsxr normally: `sudo apt install pcsxr`
2. Download the 16.04 version of pcsxr: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/pcsxr (most likely the amd64 version; `uname -a` will give display your architecture, if you see x86_64 then pick amd64 in the download)
3. Extract the deb archive (`right click` -> `extract here`). You will find a file `data.zip` that needs to be extracted as well.
4. From the data file, you'll need to copy three files. Two of the three will replace preexisting files. In the terminal, go to the extracted data file and copy the folling files:

   1. `sudo cp usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/psemu/cfgDFInput /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/psemu/cfgDFInput`
   2. `sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/psemu/libDFInput.so -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/psemu/libDFInput.so`
   3. `sudo cp /usr/share/psemu/dfinput.glade2 /usr/share/psemu/dfinput.glade2`
5. Since we're using glade again, you'll also need to install or it wont work: `sudo apt install libglade2-0`
6. This is not strictly related to this question, but the `pcsxr` package is still broken but in another way: You need to set `Cpu = 1` in `~/.pcsxr/pcsxr.cfg` or pcsxr will crash.

With that, you're all set. The configuration window should appear normally and your controller should be detected and ready for configuration.

Comment: I can confirm that is allows my controllers to be detected on my machine as well, but when try to play game, the controller just run out of control :(. the game is Tom and Jerry, I've had this issue through various OS and systems, but some other games seems to work fine. I believe it is a game specific problem, unfortunately.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20/Mint 20 a really quick, albeit temporary (and possibly limiting) solution seems to be to just unplug all but one controller, if you happen to have more pads connected. With one just controller PCSXR allowed me to open "Configure Controllers" window.