# pcsxr configuration controller window won't apper when clicked

Tags: pcsx

[How can make the controler configuration window show in pcsxr?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1173751/how-can-make-the-controler-configuration-window-show-in-pcsxr)

is where this question has already been answered but currently the link in step two does not work.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/pcsxr  a page loads and it says:

"Error

two or more packages specified (pcsxr xenial)"

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGyfa.png)

Comment: No, it doesn't say "`Error

two or more packages specified (pcsxr xenial)`". Please [edit] your Question and show us the command you used and ALL its output. When working with computers, accuracy, exactness, etc is important. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: I literally copied and pasted the error message and to be clear I am not even talking about a command. Try reading the part where i said "step two does not work" and see the link to what i am referring to.